# What are the permanent effects of a vampire bite if the character doesn't die?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead

According to the *Monster Manual* entry for [vampires](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire), the *Bite* attack has the following effects, once successful:

> *Hit:* 7 (1d6 + 4) piercing damage plus 10 (3d6) necrotic damage. The target's hit point maximum is reduced by an amount equal to the necrotic damage taken, and the vampire regains hit points equal to that amount. The reduction lasts until the target finishes a long rest. The target dies if this effect reduces its hit point maximum to 0. A humanoid slain in this way and then buried in the ground rises the following night as a vampire spawn under the vampire's control.

**If the player character doesn't die and is able to retreat (or defeat the vampire) and take a long rest, are there any long-term or permanent consequences of this bite?** Besides the mental trauma, of course?

Answer (score 29):

If the condition doesn't specify any other long-lasting effects from this bite, then there aren't any. If the target successfully takes a Long Rest, then all negative effects from the bite are removed, and there are no further implications or effects.

Comment: Beyond the usual hickey on the neck ...

Answer (score 0):

## Might not be a big deal but 2 scars on the neck could put the PC in trouble...

Especially when there's no sun around, some NPC could be suspicious about those scars and that could put the PC/group in trouble sometimes if the DM ever thinks of this.

Comment: I don't know if I should put this directly in the answer (meta related) but I indeed have 2 vampire scars on the neck in real life (scarification) and some people spotted it (damn they rolled 20!) and I had some reactions sometimes and sometimes discussion about vampires so in a game with real vampires and undead etc. I guess if the DM feels like it, it could indeed be something that could influence the roleplay/the game, there's ways to get rid of that of course, you could mutilate yourself to make another scar or some spell to remove it etc. (I also have the permanent vampire fangs...)